# Light behind solid geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating an HTML file integrating ThreeJs, basically I have created 4 Spheres, 1 of them projects the light, other 3 spheres turn in a wall. When the Spheres is behind the wall they should not reflect the light, what I supposed to do to solve this?

I've already try changing the materials of the Spheres which turns around the wall to Lambert and Phong, setting up castShadow to true, and recieveShadow to False

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var camera, scene, renderer, orbitControls;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 30, -100);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    
    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    
    escena = scene;

    esferaLuz = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.5, 16, 16);
    luzUno = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
    luzUno.angle = Math.PI / 12;
    luzUno.penumbra = 0.05;
    luzUno.decay = 2;
    luzUno.position.set(-30, 40, -5);
    mtLuzUno = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFFFFFF});
    mallaLuzUno = new THREE.Mesh(esferaLuz, mtLuzUno);
    luzUno.add(mallaLuzUno);
    escena.add(luzUno);    

    luzUno.castShadow = true;
    luzUno.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
    luzUno.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
    luzUno.shadow.camera.near = 10;
    luzUno.shadow.camera.far = 200;

    luzMap = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(luzUno);
    escena.add(luzMap);

    sombraMap = new THREE.CameraHelper(luzUno.shadow.camera);
    escena.add(sombraMap);

    var luzAmbiente = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.1 );
    escena.add(luzAmbiente);


    geometriaPlana = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 2, 2);
    mtPlano = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x000000});
    mtPlano.transparent = false;
    mtPlano.depthWrite = true;
    mallaPlano = new THREE.Mesh(geometriaPlana, mtPlano);
    mallaPlano.rotation.x = -0.5*Math.PI;
    mallaPlano.position.x = 15;
    mallaPlano.position.y = 0;
    mallaPlano.position.z = 0;
    mallaPlano.receiveShadow = true;
    escena.add(mallaPlano);

    objEsfera = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 100, 100);
    mtObjEsfera = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFFFFFF, specular:0xFFFFFF, shininess: 1024});
    mallaObjEsfera3 = new THREE.Mesh(objEsfera, mtObjEsfera);
    mallaObjEsfera3.position.set(20, 0, 0);
    mallaObjEsfera3.castShadow = true;
    mallaObjEsfera3.receiveShadow = false;
    escena.add(mallaObjEsfera3);

    objEsfera = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 100, 100);
    mtObjEsfera = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xF90E0E, specular:0xF90E0E, shininess: 512});
    mallaObjEsfera2 = new THREE.Mesh(objEsfera, mtObjEsfera);
    mallaObjEsfera2.position.set(5, 0, 0);
    mallaObjEsfera2.castShadow = true;
    mallaObjEsfera2.receiveShadow = false;
    escena.add(mallaObjEsfera2);

    objEsfera = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 100, 100);
    mtObjEsfera = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xF2E406});
    mallaObjEsfera = new THREE.Mesh(objEsfera, mtObjEsfera);
    mallaObjEsfera.position.set(-10, 0, 0);
    mallaObjEsfera.castShadow = true;
    mallaObjEsfera.receiveShadow = false;
    escena.add(mallaObjEsfera);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.renderReverseSided = false;
    renderer.sortObjects = false
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.gammaInput = true;
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;

    window.onresize = function() {
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
}

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orbitControls.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/103/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

I expect that when the spheres is behind the wall, don't show any type of reflects of light but when is on the front reflect the light .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve your intended result is to work with shadows. So you have to set `Object3D.castShadow` and `Object3D.receiveShadow` to `true` for your spheres and your ground like in the following live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/85q3sfeg/

Also keep in mind that `three.js` does not support selective lighting so far. This issue was already discussed at github right here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5180

Assuming all objects of your scene have a lit material applied, you can't define what light sources should affect what objects.

`three.js R103`